# How to save POJO with the Relation annotation in Room Peristence Library?

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, android-room, android-components

I am currently playing with Room in order to compare it with Realm and I already have so many question about the best way to do things.

In my sample app, I have a really simple model in which one a `Person` can have `Cat`s and `Dog`s.

Here the java classes.

`Cat` and `Dog` classes inherit from an `Animal` class :

```
public abstract class RoomAnimal
{

  @PrimaryKey
  public int id;

  public int age;

  public String name;

}
```

The `Cat` class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "cat")
public final class RoomCat
    extends RoomAnimal
{

}
```

The `Dog` class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "dog")
public final class RoomDog
    extends RoomAnimal
{

  public enum RoomColor
  {
    Black, White
  }

  public static final class RoomColorConverter
  {

    @TypeConverter
    public RoomColor fromString(String color)
    {
      return color != null ? RoomColor.valueOf(color) : null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String fromRealmColor(RoomColor color)
    {
      return color.toString();
    }

  }

  @TypeConverters(RoomColorConverter.class)
  public RoomColor color;

}
```

The `Person` class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
public final class RoomPerson
{

  @PrimaryKey
  public int id;

  public String name;

}
```

I also have a POJO in order to modelize the fact that a user can have cats and dogs :

```
public final class RoomPersonWithAnimals
{

  @Embedded
  public RoomPerson person;

  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id", entity = RoomDog.class)
  public List<RoomDog> dogs;

  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id", entity = RoomCat.class)
  public List<RoomCat> cats;

}
```

The question is : how to save a list of `RoomPersonWithAnimals` objects ?

I cannot use the `Insert` annotation in a `Dao` class because the `RoomPersonWithAnimals` is not an `Entity`.

For each objects of my list of `RoomPersonWithAnimals` should I run 3 requests ?

- one in order to insert the `person` attribute ;
- one in order to insert the list of `cats` ;
- one in order to insert the list of `dogs` ;

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to save a list of RoomPersonWithAnimals objects ?

You don't, at least in the `1.0.0-alpha6` version of Room, as those are not entities.

> For each objects of my list of RoomPersonWithAnimals should I play 3 requests ?

Yes. You can use [`runInTransaction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html#runInTransaction(java.lang.Runnable)) to perform those three operations inside a single SQLite transaction.

Comment: Thk you for your answer. Can you confirm me that my POJO is the right way to produce a 1 to many relations between entities ?

Comment: @rolandl: I would describe it as "a way of atomically retrieving related entities". You do not have to use `@Relation` for this. You can use `runInTransaction()` and use other entity-based DAO methods you want for pulling in the contents for your view model (or whatever). So, `@Relation` is an option but not a requirement.

Comment: @CommonWare : Thank your for your answer. But how can I produce a 1 to many relation using only a foreign key ? For example if I want to modelize the fact that a dog can be held by several persons. I cannot a the person foreign key into my animal class. Can an entity hold a list of foreign key ? I do not see this on the documentation.

Comment: @rolandl: "I cannot a the person foreign key into my animal class" -- why not?

Comment: @CommonWare : if I do that, how to manage the fact that a dog can be held by one, two or more persons ?

Comment: @rolandl: Then you have an M:N, not a 1:N, relationship, since presumably a person can have more than one cat or dog. That will require a join table (modeled as a Room entity).

Comment: @CommonWare : yes you're right ! Can you provide an example of  a join table modeled as a Room entity ?